# EF Core - multiple parents with a list of the same child (code first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first-mapping

Is there any way to represent something like this :

```
public abstract class DbEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } // <-- a GUID-String created by the domain
}

public class Carrier : DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : DbEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Street { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will always create the address-table like this :

- Id
- Street
- CarrierId
- CustomerId

The problem is, that multiple tables will have an list of addresses (not just two) and I really don't want something like :

- Id
- Street
- Parent1Id
- Parent2Id
- Parent3Id
- Parent4Id
- ...

I've also tried to set up my entities like this :

```
_modelBuilder?.Entity<Carrier>()
              .HasMany(entity => entity.Addresses);
```

Which will also create the navigation properties on the child.

I'm also understanding why, because its a many-to-one relationship and the child needs to know his parent.

However I really have no ideas to solve my 'problem'.

I was thinking about creating multiple classes/tables for my addresses like 'CustomerAddress' and 'CarrierAddress' (which inheritance from 'address'), but creating a new address table for every parent.. feels wrong?

Is this really the right way or can I solve this somehow else or is something considered 'good practise' for such cases?

Comment: Than add a property to the class that is an array : int[] parentId {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Address class with a generic type, but this will generate multiple tables with different names like this:

```cs
Address<Parent1>
Address<Parent2>
Address<Parent3>
```

If this is ok with you, you can modify Address class as:

```cs
public class Address<TParent>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Street { get; set; }
    public TParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```